How to prove that two equivalence relationship on set $X$ commutes iff they're independent in each of the component of some disjoint union of X?
Two equivalences $\alpha, \beta$ on a set $X$ are said to be independent if each equivalence class $A \in X/ \alpha$ intersect with each equivalence class $B \in X/ \beta$.
Can it be proved or disproved that given two equivalence $\alpha, \beta $ on $X$, $\alpha \circ \beta = \beta \circ \alpha$ iff exist some disjoint union of $X = \cup X_i$ such that on each $X_i$, their restriction $\alpha\restriction_{X_i}$ and $\beta\restriction_{X_i}$ are independent?
Can similar fact for congruence in certain algebra (i.e. the equivalence that also respects the algebra's operation) be proven ?
This question is inspired by rota's The many life of lattice theory, in which he states the theorem without proof.

Welcome to MathSE! What have you tried?

Can it be proved or disproved that $\ldots$ ETC. $\ldots$
This question is inspired by Rota's The many life of lattice theory, in which he states the theorem without proof.
Rota's statement is not quite correct. Let me copy his exact
statement here, give a counterexample to it, then correct it.
[Rota] Two equivalence relations are said to commute
when the underlying set may be partitioned into
disjoint blocks and the restriction of the pair of
equivalence relations to each of these blocks is a
pair of independent equivalence relations. 
(From page 1443 of:
The many lives of lattice theory, Notices of the AMS, Volume 44, Number 11, 1997.)
Counterexample. Let $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$
be the equivalence relations on $X$ that are
generated by $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ respectively.
That is, $\alpha = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,2)\}$ and
$\beta = \{(0,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$.
Then $(0,2)\in\alpha\circ\beta$, but $(0,2)\notin \beta\circ\alpha$,
so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do not commute.
Nevertheless, $X$ may be partitioned into disjoint blocks
such that the restriction of $\alpha$ and $\beta$
to each of these blocks is a pair of independent equivalence relations.
Use the partition $\Pi=\{\{0\}, \{1\}, \{2\}\}$.
One checks that, say, $\alpha|_{\{0\}} = \alpha\cap (\{0\}\times \{0\}) =
\{(0,0)\}$ and $\beta|_{\{0\}} = \{(0,0)\}$. The only
$\alpha|_{\{0\}}$-equivalence class is $\{0\}$ and the
only $\beta|_{\{0\}}$-equivalence class is $\{0\}$,
and these intersect, hence
$\alpha|_{\{0\}}$ and $\beta|_{\{0\}}$ are independent.
The same is true for
$\alpha|_{\{i\}}$ and $\beta|_{\{i\}}$ for any $\{i\}\in \Pi$.
This shows that Rota's characterization is not correct.

Correction.
Let $\alpha$ be an equivalence relation on $X$ and
let $\Pi=\{X_i\;|\;i\in I\}$ be a partition of $X$.
Let's allow ourselves to compare equivalence relations and
partitions by converting both
to equivalence relations and then comparing by $\subseteq$:
Say that an equivalence relation $\alpha$ refines a partition $\Pi$ if $\alpha\subseteq \Theta_{\Pi}$
where $\Theta_{\Pi} = \bigcup_{i\in I} X_i\times X_i$ is the equivalence
relation associated to $\Pi$. Saying that $\alpha$ refines $\Pi$
is equivalent to saying that $\alpha$ is recoverable from its restrictions to $\Pi$-cells:
$\alpha = \bigcup_{X_i\in \Pi} \alpha|_{X_i}$.
Rota's claim should be:
Theorem. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be equivalence
relations on a set $X$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute
if and only if there is a partition $\Pi=\{X_i\;|\;i\in I\}$
of $X$ that is refined by both $\alpha$ and $\beta$
such that $\alpha|_{X_i}$ is independent of $\beta|_{X_i}$
for all $X_i\in \Pi$.
Proof for 'if':
Assume that there is a partition $\Pi=\{X_i\;|\;i\in I\}$
of $X$ that is refined by both $\alpha$ and $\beta$
such that $\alpha|_{X_i}$ is independent of $\beta|_{X_i}$
for all $X_i\in \Pi$. To show that $\alpha$ commutes with $\beta$,
choose any pair $(a,b)\in\alpha\circ \beta$. There must exist $c\in X$
such that $(a,c)\in \alpha$ and $(c,b)\in\beta$. Since $\Pi$
refines both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, there is some $X_i$ that
contains the equivalence classes $[a]_{\alpha}$ and $[b]_{\beta}$,
hence $a, b, c\in X_i$. By independence, the $\beta|_{X_i}$-class containing $a$ must intersect the $\alpha|_{X_i}$-class containing $b$, so there must be some intersection point $d\in X_i$ such that $(a,d)\in \beta$ and $(d,b)\in\alpha$. This proves that $(a,b)\in\beta\circ\alpha$. Since $(a,b)\in \alpha\circ\beta$ was chosen arbitrarily,
we derive that
$\alpha\circ\beta\subseteq \beta\circ\alpha$. Applying converse to both sides of this inclusion yields
$\beta\circ\alpha\subseteq \alpha\circ\beta$,
so $\alpha\circ\beta=\beta\circ\alpha$.
Idea of proof for 'only if': Assume that $\alpha$ commutes
with $\beta$. Show that $\alpha\circ\beta$ is an equivalence relation
that is refined by both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Take $\Pi$ to be the partition of $X$ into $(\alpha\circ\beta)$-classes. It works.

Tangential comment. When consulting Rota's paper for the exact statement of his
claim I noticed another error on the same page. He writes:
[Rota] The second of Birkhoff’s theorems states that
a category of algebraic systems is endowed with
free algebras if and only if it is closed under
products and subalgebras.
Birkhoff did not prove an 'if and only if' statement,
only an 'if, then' statement.
Birkhoff showed that if a class of algebras in some signature
is closed under the formation of subalgebras and products,
then it has free algebras of every rank.
The converse is false. To see this, consider the class
$\mathcal{L}$ of free lattices. This class has free algebras
of every rank, clearly,
but it is not closed under subalgebras nor products.
To see this, note that the small-rank free lattices satisfy:

 $|F_{\mathcal{L}}(0)| = 0$

 $|F_{\mathcal{L}}(1)| = 1$

 $|F_{\mathcal{L}}(2)| = 4$,    $F_{\mathcal{L}}(2) \cong \mathbf{2}\times \mathbf{2}$

 $|F_{\mathcal{L}}(\kappa)|$ is infinite if $\kappa\geq 3$.


To see that the class of free lattices is not closed under the formation of products
notice that the product of free lattices
$F_{\mathcal{L}}(2)\times F_{\mathcal{L}}(2)$
cannot be free, since it has size 16 and there is no free lattice
of size 16.
To see that the class of free lattices is not closed under
the formation of sublattices
notice that the $3$-element chain is a sublattice of
the free lattice
$F_{\mathcal{L}}(2) \cong \mathbf{2}\times \mathbf{2}$,
but there is no free lattice
of size 3.

Thank you! I can also see it holds for congruence trivally as well!
